# I want to view admin selected product on a specific page

Tags: configurable-product

when the admin select some random products from different category  in back end . in the frontend it should be listed.

Thank you

Comment: create attribute and disaply that product in custom page

Comment: you can done this functionality by creating a custom widget, try to create a custom widget first, show code here, I will help you then

Comment: Thank you  Rk rathod  for your suggestion .